# Valid OData failing when queryed using Excel PowerQuery

Tags: excel, odata, powerquery

I'm trying to build an OData service in ASP Core for consumption in Excel and have hit a problem when trying to consume it. It's odd as other similar tables seem to be consumed fine.

Here's the response (obtained using PostMan):

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://localhost:44349/odata/$metadata#ScenarioYearValues",
    "value": [
        {
            "ScenarioYearValueId": 46
        },
        {
            "ScenarioYearValueId": 47
        },
        {
            "ScenarioYearValueId": 48
        },
        {
            "ScenarioYearValueId": 49
        },
        {
            "ScenarioYearValueId": 50
        },
        {
            "ScenarioYearValueId": 51
        },
        {
            "ScenarioYearValueId": 52
        },
        {
            "ScenarioYearValueId": 161
        },
        {
            "ScenarioYearValueId": 162
        },
        {
            "ScenarioYearValueId": 178
        }
    ]
}
```

And here's the metadata:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="4.0" xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx">
    <edmx:DataServices>
        <Schema Namespace="Backend.ImpPlanner.Models" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
            <EntityType Name="ScenarioYearValue">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="ScenarioYearValueId" />
                </Key>
                <Property Name="ScenarioYearValueId" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
            </EntityType>
        </Schema>
        <Schema Namespace="Default" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
            <EntityContainer Name="Container">
                <EntitySet Name="ScenarioYearValues" EntityType="Backend.ImpPlanner.Models.ScenarioYearValue" />
            </EntityContainer>
        </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Putting this through the OData validator running locally (https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=odatavalidator), it tells me that it's valid OData, but Excel returns:

[Details: "We were unable to resolve the type name 'ScenarioYearValues' to an EdmType"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg0rX.png)

Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong?

UPDATE:

Here's an example of a different controller that works:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://localhost:44349/odata/$metadata#ScenarioRows",
    "value": [
        {
            "ScenarioRowId": 317,
            "ScenarioId": null,
            "ContractId": null,
            "FinanceCodeId": 29,
            "SchoolId": 22,
            "DepartmentId": 2692,
            "FundId": null,
            "Description": "Budget setting 20/21  ",
            "Enabled": true,
            "CalculatorId": 37,
            "MonthProfileId": 17,
            "CashFlowProfileId": null,
            "MatEditOnly": false,
            "Notes": null
        },
        {
            "ScenarioRowId": 318,
            "ScenarioId": null,
            "ContractId": null,
            "FinanceCodeId": 18,
            "SchoolId": 22,
            "DepartmentId": 361,
            "FundId": null,
            "Description": "B/fwd from PSB 2",
            "Enabled": false,
            "CalculatorId": 37,
            "MonthProfileId": 17,
            "CashFlowProfileId": null,
            "MatEditOnly": false,
            "Notes": ""
        },
        {
            "ScenarioRowId": 319,
            "ScenarioId": null,
            "ContractId": null,
            "FinanceCodeId": 28,
            "SchoolId": 22,
            "DepartmentId": 369,
            "FundId": null,
            "Description": "  Jan 32 Oct 25 (7 year 6 leavers)",
            "Enabled": true,
            "CalculatorId": 37,
            "MonthProfileId": 17,
            "CashFlowProfileId": null,
            "MatEditOnly": false,
            "Notes": null
        },
        {
            "ScenarioRowId": 320,
            "ScenarioId": null,
            "ContractId": null,
            "FinanceCodeId": 30,
            "SchoolId": 22,
            "DepartmentId": 373,
            "FundId": null,
            "Description": "B/fwd from PSB 4",
            "Enabled": true,
            "CalculatorId": 37,
            "MonthProfileId": 17,
            "CashFlowProfileId": null,
            "MatEditOnly": false,
            "Notes": ""
        },
        {
            "ScenarioRowId": 321,
            "ScenarioId": null,
            "ContractId": null,
            "FinanceCodeId": 20,
            "SchoolId": 22,
            "DepartmentId": 2819,
            "FundId": null,
            "Description": "Budget setting 20/21  ",
            "Enabled": true,
            "CalculatorId": 37,
            "MonthProfileId": 17,
            "CashFlowProfileId": null,
            "MatEditOnly": false,
            "Notes": null
        },
        {
            "ScenarioRowId": 322,
            "ScenarioId": null,
            "ContractId": null,
            "FinanceCodeId": 43,
            "SchoolId": 22,
            "DepartmentId": 374,
            "FundId": null,
            "Description": "Lettings income 20/21 budget",
            "Enabled": true,
            "CalculatorId": 37,
            "MonthProfileId": 17,
            "CashFlowProfileId": null,
            "MatEditOnly": false,
            "Notes": null
        },
        {
            "ScenarioRowId": 323,
            "ScenarioId": null,
            "ContractId": null,
            "FinanceCodeId": 61,
            "SchoolId": 22,
            "DepartmentId": 375,
            "FundId": null,
            "Description": "B/fwd from PSB 7",
            "Enabled": true,
            "CalculatorId": 37,
            "MonthProfileId": 17,
            "CashFlowProfileId": null,
            "MatEditOnly": false,
            "Notes": null
        },
        {
            "ScenarioRowId": 324,
            "ScenarioId": null,
            "ContractId": null,
            "FinanceCodeId": 36,
            "SchoolId": 22,
            "DepartmentId": 368,
            "FundId": null,
            "Description": "B/fwd from PSB 8",
            "Enabled": true,
            "CalculatorId": 37,
            "MonthProfileId": 17,
            "CashFlowProfileId": null,
            "MatEditOnly": false,
            "Notes": null
        },
        {
            "ScenarioRowId": 325,
            "ScenarioId": null,
            "ContractId": null,
            "FinanceCodeId": 269,
            "SchoolId": 22,
            "DepartmentId": 712,
            "FundId": null,
            "Description": "B/fwd from PSB 9",
            "Enabled": true,
            "CalculatorId": 37,
            "MonthProfileId": 17,
            "CashFlowProfileId": null,
            "MatEditOnly": false,
            "Notes": ""
        },
        {
            "ScenarioRowId": 326,
            "ScenarioId": null,
            "ContractId": null,
            "FinanceCodeId": 29,
            "SchoolId": 28,
            "DepartmentId": 2692,
            "FundId": null,
            "Description": "B/fwd from PSB 10",
            "Enabled": true,
            "CalculatorId": 37,
            "MonthProfileId": 17,
            "CashFlowProfileId": null,
            "MatEditOnly": false,
            "Notes": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

And the metadata:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="4.0" xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx">
    <edmx:DataServices>
        <Schema Namespace="Backend.ImpPlanner.Models" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
            <EntityType Name="ScenarioRow">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="ScenarioRowId" />
                </Key>
                <Property Name="ScenarioRowId" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Name="ScenarioId" Type="Edm.Int32" />
                <Property Name="ContractId" Type="Edm.Int32" />
                <Property Name="FinanceCodeId" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Name="SchoolId" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Name="DepartmentId" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Name="FundId" Type="Edm.Int32" />
                <Property Name="Description" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Name="Enabled" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Name="CalculatorId" Type="Edm.Int32" />
                <Property Name="MonthProfileId" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Name="CashFlowProfileId" Type="Edm.Int32" />
                <Property Name="MatEditOnly" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Name="Notes" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="5000" />
            </EntityType>
        </Schema>
        <Schema Namespace="Backend.ImpPlanner.ViewModels" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
            <EntityType Name="ScenarioRowDetailModel" BaseType="Backend.ImpPlanner.Models.ScenarioRow">
                <Property Name="Editable" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="false" />
            </EntityType>
        </Schema>
        <Schema Namespace="Default" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
            <EntityContainer Name="Container">
                <EntitySet Name="ScenarioRows" EntityType="Backend.ImpPlanner.Models.ScenarioRow" />
            </EntityContainer>
        </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Comment: Can you show us one of the "similar" tables that work fine? I don't see anything wrong with your code snippets on the first sight.

Comment: Thanks for looking @MichaelSchönbauer, I've edited my question.

Comment: I still dont see anything wrong with your code on the ODATA-side, maybe it's some glitch in Excel. You could try and add a second property to the EntityType "ScenarioYearValues", just in case excel needs data columns in addition to the key column.

Comment: Thanks again, I thought so, but started to doubt myself! I'll give that a go, thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have exactly the same issue.

Comment: Nope, sorry, never did get to the bottom of it

Answer (score 0):

After hours of struggling with the same "We were unable to resolve the type name '[EntityName]' to an EdmType", I found that Excel's Power Query seems to cache OData metadata.  All you need to do to refresh it is click the Refresh Preview button on the Home tab of the ribbon then the error goes away.