# OData with Excel: We were unable to resolve the type name '' to an EdmType

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-core, odata

I'm developing a web API for OData, but get a strange issue when retrieving the data in Excel.

I have `/odata/books` and `/odata/presses` from a demo I found, and `/odata/cats`, which is the one I added following the same format as the other controllers, DbSets etc.

In Excel, `books` and `presses` retrieve data without any problem, but when connecting to `cats` I get the following:

[image: Error image]

My model is as follows:

```
public class Cat
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My controller is as follows:

```
public class CatsController : ODataController
{
    private BookStoreContext _db;

    public CatsController(BookStoreContext context)
    {
        _db = context;
        if (context.Cats.Count() == 0)
        {
            foreach (var b in DataSource.GetCats())
            {
                context.Cats.Add(b);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    [EnableQuery]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(_db.Cats);
    }
}
```

My EdmModel is as follows:

```
private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<Cat>("Cats");
    builder.EntitySet<Book>("Books");
    builder.EntitySet<Press>("Presses"); 
    
    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: This gets even stranger, if I user power query in excel to build the query, it works fine.

I noticed however that excel told me during creation that the data could be two days old and gave me the option to refresh, leading me to believe there is some caching going on. So between first attempt and now, caching may have been giving me false negatives.

Maybe inbetween my first query and

Comment: Did you get this to work? I have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Per [my answer on a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68720702)...

After hours of struggling with the same "We were unable to resolve the type name '[EntityName]' to an EdmType", I found that Excel's Power Query seems to cache OData metadata. All you need to do to refresh it is click the Refresh Preview button on the Home tab of the ribbon then the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get this message in PowerBI?
I was just fighting with the same issue: in Chrome/Edge etc. my OData feed just worked fine, in PowerBI I got this (strange) error message.

Just literally a few minutes ago, I found a solution for in PowerBI. When connect to an OData feed, you need to click 'advanced' and that also check the 'Include open type columns'. For me that seems to work so far.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using OData V4?  Does using OData V2 solve this?  For some reason, PowerBI seems to have an issue with some V4 OData feeds that Excel's Power Query can handle without issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).